# Do pointers need to be dropped at the end of unit tests?

Tags: rust

I have many unit tests that instantiate pointers to test data, I currently drop all these pointers after my test assertions, will dangling pointers in unit tests introduce undesired behaviour, or can I trust the test runner to clean this up for me?

e.g;

```
#[test]
fn unit_test() {
  let mut test_data_vec = hex::decode(
    "3030000ee92494",
  )
  .ok()
  .unwrap();
  let test_data_ptr = test_data_vec.as_mut_ptr();

  //... use ptr in tests

  // currently I explicitly drop pointer, is this required?
  unsafe {
    drop_in_place(test_data_ptr);
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "dropping pointers"?  Normally, pointers (like other values) are dropped automatically when they go out of scope, and dropping a pointer is a no-op.  Can you provide a [mre]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends on the method that provides the pointer. If you struct's method has following signature, I would say you have to drop it.

```rust
impl YourStruct {
  fn into_ptr(self) -> *mut () {
    // …
  }
}
```

An example is provided by [`Box::into_raw(b: Box<T, A>) -> *mut T`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.into_raw). If you use `into_raw`, you have to clean up the memory.

Given your code example, you are using [`Vec::as_mut_ptr(&mut self) -> *mut T`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/alloc/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.as_mut_ptr). Here the documentation tells you that if the vec gets dropped, the pointer goes a way. There is no need to call `drop_in_place`.